# How to change default Literally Canvas drawing region height?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to set [Literally Canvas](http://literallycanvas.com/index.html) drawing region height to some custom value (let it be `500px`). The following is stated in the docs:

> To change the height of the drawing, set a CSS height rule on the element passed to `LC.init()` or the React component that contains Literally Canvas.

So I have tried the following:

## HTML

```
<div class='my-drawing' style='height: 500px;'></div>
```

## JS

```
LC.init(document.getElementsByClassName('my-drawing')[0])
```

But the height is still default `369px`. The height of the `div` is `500px`.

## EDIT

Added JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w5kfb3qx/

Any suggestions?

Comment: canvas.height = 500 sets the pixel height (resolution), canvas.style.height =" 500px" sets the canvas display height. Same for width

Comment: @Blindman67, ok, and what about the official docs? "**To change the height of the drawing**, set a **CSS height** rule on the element passed to LC.init() or the React component that contains Literally Canvas." Doing something like $('.my-div').find('canvas').height(500); looks more like a hack, not the expected way.

Comment: That is the HTML5 standard way of setting the canvas resolution. It can not be done any other way, at some point any lib/framework/etc will have to set the canvas width and height attributes directly to change the resolution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas has some info but the link to the Specifications "HTML5" standard seems to be broken.

Comment: @Blindman67, possibly you have misunderstood me. I know the difference between canvas pixel size and display size. The problem is, I need to tell Literally Canvas to set the pixel size to 500. Just doing canvas.height = 500 will not work, because the library resizes the canvas internally after that (yes, I have tested this).

Comment: I can not seem to reproduce the error. On their demo page changing the container's height results in an undersized canvas centering on the available space.  Changing the canvas via `lc.setImageSize(foo,bar)` or directly `canvas.style.height = (canvas.height = 500) + "px"` does the same thing.  How ever I change it the new size remains and everything works fine. I think the problem may be in some CSS rules that the canvas is inheriting on your page.

Comment: @Blindman67, added a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w5kfb3qx/ Anyway, accessing the widget's internal elements directly (I mean NOT using the API) is a hack, and is NOT OK. BTW, canvas.style.height = canvas.height = 500; does not help: the canvas is resized, but it's lower part is not visible. As you can see, there is no extra CSS rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

To make the `canvas` resize properly, one have to call the `respondToSizeChange` method on a Literally Canvas instance.

```
var lc = LC.init(document.getElementsByClassName('my-drawing')[0]);

lc.respondToSizeChange();
```

It is also a good idea to call this method every time the parent element is resized.

Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/cy5cknq7/3/

**Note**: This method is not documented. So it is more of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

To change the height of (1 in the picture) use inline style :

```
    <div class='my-drawing' style='height: 500px;'></div>
```

To change the height of (2 in the picture) this code :

```
    LC.init(element, {imageSize: {width: 500, height: null}})
```

and use pan button (on the left panel)

[image]